# Character class bug in nvi: [[:digit:]] is interpreted like [[:alnum:]]

Tags: vi, nvi

A simple search in **nvi** on text such as:

```
the quick red fox jumped 1 foot over the lazy 28 pound dog
```

using the following search

```
/[[:digit:]]
```

behaves like

```
/[[:alnum:]]
```

That is, it finds every character when repeated.  For that matter all of the bracket expressions I tried behaved as alnum.  However

```
/[0-9]
```

worked as expected just finding 1, 2, and 8. I've been using nvi for some time but there's a yawning chasm in my knowledge here.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Any class name that is 5 characters long (i.e. all of them except `xdigit`) is interpreted as `alnum`, all for the lack of one little character. The patch is simple:

```
--- regex/regcomp.c~
+++ regex/regcomp.c
@@ -819,7 +819,7 @@
                NEXT();
        len = p->next - sp;
        for (cp = cclasses; cp->name != NULL; cp++)
-               if (STRLEN(cp->name) == len && MEMCMP(cp->name, sp, len))
+               if (STRLEN(cp->name) == len && !MEMCMP(cp->name, sp, len))
                        break;
        if (cp->name == NULL) {
                /* oops, didn't find it */
```

I haven't reported the bug nor found it reported anywhere. Please do so and follow back here.